# paypal error code 10413: when items are not select in full

Tags: paypal

Paypal sent me the Express Checkout API. For single item purchase, it is working fine. However, when I added in >1 times, I get the following error.

> Error code 10413 : The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.

This error will not happen if I select all the items. However, the error happens when I select one item.

My link is http://dotdesign.com.sg/paypal.php feel free to test out. I hope someone has the solution.

Comment: You should post your code here instead.

Comment: If you are trying the link, try to select the first item only and you will get the error. However, if you select the first 3 items, it will work.